# pascal triangle

Tags: c

I am trying to write code for printing Pascal's triangle. I wrote the following program, but the output format is not same as what I'm trying to accomplish.

**Code Listing**

---

```
void main(){
    int a[15][15],row,num=25,i,j,k;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Num of rows");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(k=num-2*i;k>=0;k--)
            printf("");

        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            if(j==0||i==j){
                a[i][j]=1;
            }else{
                a[i][j]=a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j];
            }
            printf("%6d",a[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
```

The above output isn't what I want though. I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```
      1
    1   1
  1   2   1
1   3   3   1
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample output for say, the first 5 rows? Also, what output did you expect?

Comment: If your textbook told you to use `void main()`, the author doesn't know C very well. Find a better book.

Comment: Ok, you just need to see the pattern of how many spaces are added as you descend each row and add those spaces to the front of your number print out.  Also, 3 spaces between numbers instead of 1.

Comment: @Dogbert Hi Dogbert pls check it now...Thanks

Comment: Thanks Halex for helping me by editing

Comment: sorry, i dint get u @MichaelDorgan

Comment: Try putting a space in your first printf: printf("") -> printf(" ");

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with your `printf("");` statement

make it `printf(" ");` by adding a space.

Your original `printf("");` statement doesn't add any change to the format of your output.

Where as `printf(" ");` prints a white space with each iteration of the loop,

```
for(k=num-2*i;k>=0;k--)
```

Comment: Yup, that's worth one now.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `printf("");` with `printf(" ");`

(difference is a space between the quotes)